# ||gm is formed by the lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ and the lines through $(p,q)$ parallel to them. Find the equation of the diagonal

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

> A parallelogram is formed by the lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ and the lines through $(p,q)$ parallel to them and the equation of the diagonal of the parallelogram which doesn't pass through the origin is $(\lambda x-p)(ap+hq)+(\phi y-q)(hp-bp)=0$ then find the value of $\lambda^3+\phi^3$

I have found the slopes of the lines by comparing the coefficients of the various terms in $(m_1x-y+c_1)(m_2x-y+c_2)=0$ and the given equation for the $2$ lines. Hence I obtain $m_1 m_2=\frac{a}{b}$ and $m_1+m_2=-2h$  which can be solved to get the slopes.

$$m_1=\frac{-h-\sqrt{h^2-4ab}}{2}$$

$$m_2=\frac{-h+\sqrt{h^2-4ab}}{2}$$

After this I have tried to find the intersection of the lines to obtain the opposite points connecting the required diagonal. The points I obtain are quite complex and seem to be incorrect. My procedure also seems quite long.

Is there a shorter method to obtain the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Useful fact:** For hyperbola, the tangency point bisects the line segment of the tangent between the asymptotes.

- $h^2-ab>0$
- Hyperbola passes through $\left( \frac{p}{2}, \frac{q}{2}\right)$
  $$4(ax^2+2hxy+by^2)=ap^2+2hpq+bq^2$$
- Asymptotes
  $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$$
- Tangent at $(x',y')$

$$4[ax'x+h(y'x+x'y)+by'y]=ap^2+2hpq+bq^2$$

- Two diagonals bisect each other at 
  $\left( \frac{p}{2}, \frac{q}{2}\right)$.
- The tangent at $\left( \frac{p}{2}, \frac{q}{2}\right)$ is the diagonal **not** passing through the origin, i.e.

$$2[apx+h(qx+py)+bqy]=ap^2+2hpq+bq^2$$

$$2(ap+hq)x+2(hp+bq)y=p(ap+hq)+q(hp+bq)$$

$$(ap+hq)(2x-p)+(hp+bq)(2y-q)=0$$

$$\lambda=\phi=2$$

$$\fbox{$\lambda^3+\phi^3=16$}$$

See another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976239/coordinate-geometry-high-level-problems/1836860#1836860) for your interest.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, how did you think of this?

Comment: @Sawarnik, While I'm trying to considering the constant term of $(\lambda x-p)(ap+hq)+(\phi y-q)(hp-bp)=0$, $$ap^2+2hpq+bq^2$$ pops out.  That's closely related to conics.  Of course, a plot of the mentioned hyperbola really helps.